# Immediate NaN in loss function with custom activation without extreme batch size--how to prevent exploding gradients?

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, keras

Using a custom activation function, when using SGD as an optimiser, except for setting the batch number to an excessively high value the loss will return as an NaN at some stage during training. Using Adam as an optimiser, this happens immediately regardless of batch size.

The reduced version of code used to test this:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np

class CustomActivation(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomActivation, self).__init__()

    def call(self, inputs):
        x, y = inputs
        return 1.0 / (1.0 + tf.math.exp(-1*(0.5*x*(1+tf.math.exp(2*x*y)))))
    
    
# load data
fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

# divide to be between 0 and 1
train_images = train_images / 255.0
test_images = test_images / 255.0

stuff = []
for i in range (60000):
    stuff.append([0])

stuff = np.asarray(stuff)

stuff2 = []
for i in range (10000):
    stuff2.append([0])

stuff2 = np.asarray(stuff2)

# declare inputs
input1 = keras.Input(shape=(28,28,))
input2 = keras.Input(shape=(1,))

#flatten
flat1 = layers.Flatten()(input1)

# weight and output layers
primary_1 = layers.Dense(10,)(flat1)
secondary_1 = layers.Dense(10,)(input2)
out = CustomActivation()([primary_1,secondary_1])

# declare model
model = keras.Model(inputs=[input1,input2],outputs=out)
model.summary()

# train and test
opt = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.05)

model.compile(
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=opt,
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)


model.fit([train_images,stuff], train_labels, batch_size=20480, epochs=10)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate([test_images,stuff2], test_labels, verbose=2)

print('\nTest accuracy:', test_acc)
```

If the secondary input is set to any value other than zeros, then even a batch size of 20480 is too small.

As this is the fashion MNIST dataset, there are no NaN values in the input. Running such a large batch size in a more complicated network is unfeasible. Including l2 or l1 regularisation doesn't allow for reducing the batch size.

It seems like a classic case of exploding gradients; the partial derivatives of activation for x and y are (calculated normally):
$$
\frac{dA}{dx}=\frac{1}{2}+(\frac{1}{2}+xy)\exp(2xy)
$$
and
$$
\frac{dA}{dy}=x^{2}\exp(2xy)
$$
However, it seems that as of Tensorflow 2, gradient clipping is deprecated--at minimum, no longer referenced in the documentation--so what can be done to avoid running into NaN so quickly in training?

Comment: When doing numerical programming, any time you use an exponential function, you have to be very careful that the results doesn't overflow. So, what you need to do to start debugging this is either ensure that you never give an input to `exp` that's too large, or else work on a different scale. (Clipping `exp` doesn't seem like it would work in this case, because that would stop the optimizer from working correctly.)

Comment: Even with the function modified to use `tf.math.divide_no_nan` instead (which leads to strictly opposite behaviour) it leads to NaN in loss. However, extremely high input values are not a problem, assuming that tensorflow behaviour is here the same as numpy behaviour for the same operation: anywhere that there would be an overflow causes the operation to return the correct limiting value of 0 or 1. Or do you mean that the exp overflow interrupts the gradient calculation?

Comment: The gradient of `exp` is also `exp`, so if `exp` overflows, the gradient overflows, and you're appling `NaN` to your updates.

Comment: It seems the problem must extend beyond simple overflow--even applying clip as the activation function for the otherwise linear layers (`clip = lambda x : tf.clip_by_value(x,-2,2)`) has surprisingly little impact--SGD will now run with batch size 32 in this example, but Adam still doesn't work at all. With more complicated structure SGD doesn't work either.

Comment: In what specific way does it not work?

Comment: Loss is NaN from the absolute outset. Which is odd, because it worked fine with the even more basic scenario of binary crossentropy and learning XOR, so it feels like the activation isn't inherently incompatible.